# Simple way to read and write name value text file

Tags: c#, .net, file, text

I have some class with lots of fields;

```
public class CrowdedHouse
{
  public int     value1;
  public float   value2;
  public Guid    value3;
  public string  Value4;

  // some more fields below
}
```

My classmust be (de)serialized into simple Windows text file in the following format

```
NAME1=VALUE1
NAME2=VALUE2
```

What is the most convinient way to do that in .NET? This is a text file and all the values must be fist converted to string. Let's assume I have already converted all data to strings.

UPDATE One option would be pinvoke WritePrivateProfileString/WritePrivateProfileString
but these are using the required "[Section]" field that I don't need to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** If you have already converted each data value to strings, simply use the method below to serialize it after making a `Dictionary` of these values:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "value1", "value1value" },
    { "value2", "value2value" },
    // etc
}
```

or use `dict.Add(string key, string value)`.

---

To read the data, simply split each line around the `=` and store the results as a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.ext");
var dict = lines.Select(l => l.Split('=')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

To convert a dictionary to the file, use:

```
string[] lines = dict.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + "=" + kvp.Value).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(lines);
```

Note that your `NAME`s and `VALUE`s cannot contain `=`.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to modify the writing code, I had to add a second parameter to the `WriteAllLines` method. `File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\myFolder\myFile.txt", lines);` Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Writing is easy:

```
// untested
using (var file = System.IO.File.CreateText("data.txt"))
{
   foreach(var item in data)
      file.WriteLine("{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

And for reading it back:

```
// untested
using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenText("data.txt"))
{
   string line;
   while ((file.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       string[] parts = line.Split('=');
       string key = parts[0];
       string value = parts[1];
       // use it
   }
}
```

But probably the best answer is : Use XML.

Comment: That's gonna cause problems if the value part has an '=' in it . . .

Comment: Nope, neither value nor name part contain '=' character.

Comment: maybe you should specify what 'data' is. I assume a Dictionary<string,string>.

Answer (score 4):

Minor improvement of Captain Comic answer:

To enable = in values: (will split only once)

```
var dict = lines.Select(l => l.Split(new[]{'='},2)).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```